# How to get the count of specific letters in a String? (Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to count the number of times a letter's present in a String.

For example:

str = "/data/name/data/name"

How do we get the number of `/` in this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val count = str.count { it == '/' }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I am not sure whether you need an answer in java or kotlin (your tags include both), so if you need an answer in java:

```java
String input = "/data/name/data/name";
char search = '/'; 
long count = input.chars().filter(ch -> ch == search).count();
```

(and if you need a kotlin version, just take a look at [@Ivo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457115/15749574))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count with this way,

```
val str = "/data/name/data/name"
var count = 0
str.forEach {
   if(it == '/'){
       count++
   }
}
```